# Unknown hanging when I use Numeric in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I got no idea why my code breaks Xcode, it does not throw an error or warning, but also it get hanged for no reason! What I am doing wrong there?

*Xcode Version 13.2.1 (13C100)*

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var activeValue: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet(oldValue) {
            didSetFunction(totalValue: 10, oldValue: oldValue, value: &activeValue)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("+") { activeValue += 1.0 }
    }
}

func didSetFunction<T>(totalValue: T, oldValue: T, value: inout T) where T: Numeric & Comparable {
    if (oldValue != value) {
        if (value >= totalValue) { value = totalValue }
        else if (value < 0) { value = 0 }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "for no reason"? Obviously there _is_ a reason. And that reason is pretty obvious. You have an infinite recursion and (gasp) a stack overflow.

Comment: But I tried to have `(oldValue != value)` in my function, I was thinking it would solve the issue.

Comment: `inout` _always_ sets its target. Even if your code never changes `value`, the mere presence of `value` as an `inout` sets that value — which is your `activeValue`. You could delete the whole body of `didSetFunction` but you'd get the same issue.

Comment: If the reason were obvious, the question wouldn't have been posted. What's obvious to an expert is often opaque to a novice.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a pretty interesting question because, as you wrote in a comment on @matt's answer, “it has no issue using same method for didSet of a custom struct, how ever using my method in view combined with State wrapper make issue!”

So, what's happening in your code, where you use `@State`? Let's de-sugar it to figure it out. We'll go through two phases of de-sugaring.

First, let's rewrite your code to remove the `inout` parameter. In theory, Swift implements an `inout` parameter by passing a copy of the value into the receiving function, and then when the function returns, it assigns the possibly-modified parameter value back to its original storage. (In practice it may use a more efficient implementation, but the effect must be equivalent.) We'll make that explicit by returning the possibly-modified value instead of using `inout`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var activeValue: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet(oldValue) {
            activeValue = update(totalValue: 10, oldValue: oldValue, value: activeValue)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button("+") { activeValue += 1.0 }
    }
}

func update<T>(totalValue: T, oldValue: T, value: T) -> T
where T: Numeric & Comparable {
    guard oldValue != value else { return value }
    return max(0, min(value, totalValue))
}
```

Now the assignment back to `activeValue` is explicit.

Next, we'll de-sugar the use of the `@State` property wrapper. When you use a property wrapper like `@State` that has a `projectedValue` property, Swift converts your property into **three** properties: one stored property and two computed properties. They look like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private var _activeValue: State<CGFloat> = State(wrappedValue: 1.0)

    private var $activeValue: Binding<CGFloat> { _activeValue.projectedValue }

    private var activeValue: CGFloat {
        get { _activeValue.wrappedValue }
        nonmutating set {
            let oldValue = _activeValue.wrappedValue

            _activeValue.wrappedValue = newValue

            // THIS IS YOUR didSet CODE.
            activeValue = update(totalValue: 10, oldValue: oldValue, value: activeValue)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button("+") { activeValue += 1.0 }
    }
}
```

Now we can see why your `@State`-using code has infinite recursion. The `activeValue` setter calls `update` and assigns the result to `activeValue`. Since `activeValue` is a computed property, the only way to perform this assignment is by calling the `activeValue` setter again—from inside the `activeValue` setter!

Let's compare that with a version that doesn't use `@State`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private var activeValue: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet(oldValue) {
            activeValue = update(totalValue: 10, oldValue: oldValue, value: activeValue)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button("+") {
            var me = self
            me.activeValue += 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

In this version, the assignment to `activeValue` happens directly within the `didSet` observer of the `activeValue` stored property. When a `didSet` observer of a stored property assigns to its own property, Swift does **not** call the `willSet` and `didSet` observers of that property again. So there is no recursion.

(The calls to `willSet` and `didSet` are only suppressed if the assignment happens directly inside the body of the `didSet` observer. If `didSet` calls out to a function that then performs the assignment, that will recursively call `didSet`.)

Comment: Thanks for your time for answering, my method in my question try to have less foot print as much as possible with calling a Void function, in your answer, you are using a function which returns a value in end, frankly I am not big fan of such method. Are you believe your answer is more efficient than a Void function? which, in Void function would mostly happen nothing in some case would value updated via inout.

Comment: The two functions probably have identical performance in a Release build. Are you calling this function hundreds of thousands of times per second so that its performance matters?

Comment: I am not calling so much 'hundreds of thousands of times per second' but it would called so many times, in my question I just tried to simplify the issue and presented a Button for updating, but the method in question will be called so many times.

Comment: If you are concerned about the performance of `inout` versus returning a value, that sounds like a completely separate question from your original question, and should be posted separately.

Comment: You are right there, the reason of discussing about it has been started with reading your answer.

Comment: Comments aren't for extended discussion of other questions. If I (or matt) have answered your original question, then you should click the check mark next to the answer. If you have a related question, you should click the “Ask Question” button at the very top of the page to post your new question separately.

Comment: I know that, your answer use other method than my method, I cannot try your method or codes because your answer returns value, my question does not. :(

Comment: Sounds like you should post a new question asking how to change a method that takes an `inout` parameter to one that does not.

Comment: No, why? my current question is what I asked and it has inout in question from beginning.

Comment: Your question, copied and pasted from your original post, is “What I am doing wrong there?” Both matt and I explained what you're doing wrong: you're causing `didSet` to be invoked recursively. I also explained why it's not wrong if you don't use `@State`. The solution is to not assign to the property in its own `didSet` observer (including by not passing the property as an `inout` parameter), if you're using `@State` (or any other property wrapper).

Comment: I do not understand your comment or what you mean by `Your question, copied and pasted from your original post`

Comment: Read your original post at the top of this page. There is only one sentence ending with a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite recursion and consequently a stack overflow:

```
7   SwiftApp   0x10a15c6ba ContentView.activeValue.setter + 234
8   SwiftApp   0x10a15c2d5 ContentView.activeValue.didset + 229 (ContentView.swift:15)
9   SwiftApp   0x10a15c6d9 ContentView.activeValue.setter + 265
10  SwiftApp   0x10a15c2d5 ContentView.activeValue.didset + 229 (ContentView.swift:15)
11  SwiftApp   0x10a15c6d9 ContentView.activeValue.setter + 265
12  SwiftApp   0x10a15c2d5 ContentView.activeValue.didset + 229 (ContentView.swift:15)
13  SwiftApp   0x10a15c6d9 ContentView.activeValue.setter + 265
14  SwiftApp   0x10a15c2d5 ContentView.activeValue.didset + 229 (ContentView.swift:15)
... (and so on)
```

Your `activeValue` setter calls a function that changes (through the `inout` parameter) the value of `activeValue` — which triggers the setter, which calls the function, which changes the value, which triggers the setter, which calle\s the function, which changes the value... Loop-loop-loop-kaboom.

Comment: @Fullcode Remove the function and put the code directly into your `didSet` handler. Or use a normal `return` instead of `inout`.

Comment: @matt: By the way I looked more on testing my codes in question, it has no issue using same method for didSet of a custom struct, how ever using my method in view combined with State wrapper make issue! Your comments and this Answer are not valid to accepted as correct answer in this case. because my codes work fine, the reason was about State not inout.

Comment: Whatever. All I'm doing is responding to your "hangs for no reason". There's a reason and I told you what it was.

Comment: Whatever. Have a good day.

Comment: Have a good day also. :)